After upgrade to 24.04 strange display in nautilus
After a difficult upgrade from 23 to 24.04 I have a strange behavior in nautilus (and some other software).
Nautilus shown no file names but only the small icon at the beginning of the line:
nautilus file names missing
When moving the cursor over the invisible entries they show up as usual. Every directory I have first to "paint" with the cursor to view the content.
Some of the programs do not show entries even after the "painting" movement with the cursor (inspector):
content of inspactor
Everything on a regular PC with standard graphic card.
Any ideas?
Can work but it's not the way would continue...
Michael

Looks like it's a bug in Nautilus and I faced this issue with others. I tried this solution and it instantly fixed everything. I hope this will help you too.

I added GSK_RENDERER=gl to /etc/environment, logged in again and the bug is solved. Thanks!

Excellent!
Since Ubuntu 24.04, my Nautilus was in a mess: flickering and having strange behaviour!
This tweak fixed everything!
Thanks!

First - delete thumbnails cache from
/home/user/.cache/thumbnails


Not a complete answer. A complete answer would have instructions on hos to find the directory and how to remove the files. Also there is already an accepted answer.
